# Change Twitter stream filter keywords without re-opening stream

Tags: api, twitter

Is it possible to change the filter keywords on a Twitter stream while it's open?

I'm looking to follow the second point of the http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api pre-launch checklist, "Creating the minimal number of connections", and avoid closing and re-opening the stream each time the keywords I wish to follow change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can't change the filter predicate without reconnecting, but the streaming-api concepts page has instructions [how change the predicates](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_concepts#updating-filter-predicates) and making the user experience as smooth as possible

Comment: Thanks for this. If you could site a definitive source for it not being possible to change predicates without reconnecting I'd be happy to accept your answer as correct.

Comment: "Reconnect to update filter predicates when the user adds a new track query"

Comment: also see http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_concepts#connecting "To connect to the Streaming API, form a HTTP request and consume the resulting stream for as long as is practical"

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation says you cannot update the filter predicates; http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_concepts#updating-filter-predicates