# How to change keywords on twitter stream api using twitter4j?

Tags: twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I am using twitter4j to connect to Stream API.

I understand that from this post, [Change Twitter stream filter keywords without re-opening stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275228/change-twitter-stream-filter-keywords-without-re-opening-stream), there is no way to change keywords while the connection is open. I have to disconnect and change the filter predicate and reconnect it.

I would like to know if there is any code sample that would allow me to disconnect it, change the keywords and reconnect it?

Currently, I tried to do this in the StatusListener under onStatus() where after an X amount of time has passed, it will change the keyword to "juice". But there is no method for me to close the connection and reconnect to Stream API.

```
if (diff>=timeLapse) {
   StatusListener listener = createStatusListener();
   track = "juice";
   twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
   twitterStream.addListener(listener);
   FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
   fq.track(new String[] {track});
   startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
   twitterStream.filter(fq);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cleanUp() the stream first and then open a new stream with filter(FilterQuery) method to change track terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply calling `Filter(query)` again, no need to call `cleanUp()` as calling `filter(query)` does this for you. Here's how I do this, and there is no need to stop/restart the stream !

```
private TwitterStream twitterStream;

private void filterTwitterStream() {

    if (conditionToStopStreaming) {
        if (null != twitterStream) {
            twitterStream.shutdown();
            twitterStream = null;
        }
    } else {
        if (twitterStream == null) {
            twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(getConfiguration()).getInstance();
            twitterStream.addListener(getListener());
        }

        FilterQuery qry = new FilterQuery();

        String[] keywords = {......}
        qry.track(keywords);

        twitterStream.filter(qry);
    }
}
```

Where `getConfiguration()` returns my `Configuration` object and  `getListener()` returns my defined `StatusListener()` object